# Xcode 9 GM - Simulator for ios 11 stuck on apple

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, xcode9

1,2,3 devices is iOS 11, 4 is iOS 8.4
I tried to restart or wait for 30 mins. It looks like an apple with progress bar. Then progress bar completes and disappears and I see only apple forever.

It never worked for me. I just downloaded Xcode 9 and can't run iOS 11 simulator.

[image]

Any ideas how to fix it?

Xcode Version 9.0 (9A235)

Comment: Tried loading 1 at a time?

Comment: @ZaidKhan yes. I tried to load only iPhone X + iOS11 or only iPhone 5S + iOS 11. The same issue.

Comment: Try deleting derived data and resetting simulator (Simulator > Hardware > Erase All Content and Settings...)

Comment: @ZaidKhan thank you for your advice, but it didn't help too. Also I tried to restart my mac.

Comment: @JohnKakon Please file a bug at https://bugreport.apple.com. With all these devices booted run `xcrun simctl diagnose` and attach the tarball it generates. Also attach the tarball from `sudo sysdiagnose -q`. If you don't mind you can also zip the contents of `~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator` and attach that. I am very curious why those devices are getting stuck attempting to boot. Reply here with the radar # and I will look at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just updated macOS to High Sierra and Xcode to Release Version 9.0 (9A235) and issue was fixed.

(The issue was not about running multiple devices at once. Single emulator stuck too)

Answer (score 0):

If you tried booting all of them at the same time, it is quite possible that you are near the resource limit for your system, so processes are failing to fork/exec.

If you boot successive devices after previous ones have finished booting, it is better behaved at detecting this scenario and will present you with an alert window that it won't attempt to boot the next device.  It also will point you to the Simulator Help documentation which contains information on increasing your system limits.

Answer (score 0):

You should run one simulator wait for it to show device desktop then start up another device when desktop appears boot up another device and so on. Hopefully it Could Help.

Answer (score -1):

Open Terminal and try this:

**xcrun simctl erase all**